# How to show a message when cart is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, cart

I created a shopping cart using Javascript. I'm trying to output a "Your cart is empty." with an image message when the shopping cart is empty. This is my displayCart

```
function displayCart() {
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
// cart = parseInt(cart);

let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');


if( cartItems && productContainer ) {
    productContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(cartItems).map( (item, index) => {
        productContainer.innerHTML += 
        `<div class="product"><ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon><img src="assets/images/${item.title}.jpg" width=200px height=150px/>
            <span class="sm-hide">${item.title}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="price sm-hide">₹${item.price}.00</div>
        <div class="quantity">
            <ion-icon class="decrease " name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
                <span>${item.inCart}</span>
            <ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>   
        </div>
        <div class="total">₹${item.inCart * item.price}.00</div>`;
    }); 

    productContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="basketTotalContainer">
            <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                Basket Total
            </h4>
            <h4 class="basketTotal">
            ₹${cartCost}.00
            </h4>
    `;

}

deleteButtons();
manageQuantity();
```

}

This is my products div

```
    <div class="container-products">
    <div class="product-header">
        <h5 class="product-title">PRODUCT</h5>
        <h5 class="price sm-hide">PRICE</h5>
        <h5 class="quantity">QUANTITY</h5>
        <h5 class="total">TOTAL</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="products">

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display this when my cart is empty. How can i do this .Help me please

```
<div class="empty-cart">
    <h1>Cart Empty </h1>
    <p>You Haven't Ordered a pizza yet.
        To order a pizza go to the main page.
    </p>
    <img src="assets/images/empty-cart.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Your items are in an array called `cartItems`. You don't know how to write an if statement like `if (cardtItems.length === 0) .. cart is empty, draw your div .. else .. draw div with card items ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Now is better ?

html

```
 <div class="container-products">
    <div class="product-header">
        <h5 class="product-title">PRODUCT</h5>
        <h5 class="price sm-hide">PRICE</h5>
        <h5 class="quantity">QUANTITY</h5>
        <h5 class="total">TOTAL</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="products">

    </div>

    <div class="emtyproducts">

    </div>
```

js

```
    function displayCart() { 
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    
    let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
    // cart = parseInt(cart);
    
    let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
 
    let containerPoduct = document.querySelector('.container-products');
    containerPoduct.style.display ='none';
    let emptyPoduct = document.querySelector('.emtyproducts');
    emptyPoduct.style.display ='none';

    if( cartItems.length === 0 && productContainer ) {
        containerPoduct.style.display ='';

        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map( (item, index) => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += 
            `<div class="product"><ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon><img src="assets/images/${item.title}.jpg" width=200px height=150px/>
                <span class="sm-hide">${item.title}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price sm-hide">₹${item.price}.00</div>
            <div class="quantity">
                <ion-icon class="decrease " name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
                    <span>${item.inCart}</span>
                <ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>   
            </div>
            <div class="total">₹${item.inCart * item.price}.00</div>`;
        }); 
    
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="basketTotalContainer">
                <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                    Basket Total
                </h4>
                <h4 class="basketTotal">
                ₹${cartCost}.00
                </h4>
        `;
    
    }
      else
        {
          emptyPoduct.innerHTML = '<div lass="empty-cart">    <h1>Cart Empty </h1>    <p>You Haven t Ordered a pizza yet.  To order a pizza go to the main page.
        </p>  <img src="assets/images/empty-cart.png" alt="">
    </div>';
emptyPoduct.style.display ='';
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works but I want to hide .div.container-products and only show the empty-cart. But by doing above code it shows both divs.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think he wants to render either `div.container-products` or `div.empty-cart` right? You could achieve this by setting the `display` css property of both HTML elements (one to none and one to e.g. inline) depending on the length of `cartItems`. Look here for how you can set css properties: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Yes  I want to display either .div.container-products or div.empty-cart.

Comment: Ok, than as I said you could simply adjust the css properties:

`let containerProducts = document.querySelector('.container-products');
let emptyCart = document.querySelector('.empty-cart');

if (cartItems.length > 0) {
  containerProducts.style.display = 'inline';
  emptyCart.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  containerProducts.style.display = 'none';
  emptyCart.style.display = 'inline';
}`
Please check, if style property value `inline` fits your needs.

Comment: Can you again post what you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code , you need to add  `let emptycart= document.querySelector('.empty-cart');` in javascript and then in else condition you can set design

```
function displayCart() {
            let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
            cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
        
            let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
            // cart = parseInt(cart);
        
            let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
            let emptycart= document.querySelector('.empty-cart');
            let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
        
            
            if( cartItems && productContainer ) {
                productContainer.innerHTML = '';
                Object.values(cartItems).map( (item, index) => {
                    productContainer.innerHTML += 
                    `<div class="product"><ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon><img src="assets/images/${item.title}.jpg" width=200px height=150px/>
                        <span class="sm-hide">${item.title}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price sm-hide">₹${item.price}.00</div>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <ion-icon class="decrease " name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
                            <span>${item.inCart}</span>
                        <ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="total">₹${item.inCart * item.price}.00</div>`;
                }); 
        
                productContainer.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="basketTotalContainer">
                        <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                            Basket Total
                        </h4>
                        <h4 class="basketTotal">
                        ₹${cartCost}.00
                        </h4>
                `;
        
            }
        else
            {
              emptycart.innerHTML = '
    <div lass="empty-cart">
      <h1>Cart Empty </h1>
         <p>You Haven t Ordered a pizza yet.  To order a pizza go to the main page.</p>  
<img src="assets/images/empty-cart.png" alt="">
        </div>'
            }
            deleteButtons();
            manageQuantity();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="empty">Empty</div>
    <div id="not-empty">Not Empty</div>
    <script>
      const empty = document.getElementById("empty");
      const notEmpty = document.getElementById("not-empty");
    
      // const array = [];
      const array = ['element'];
    
      if (array.length === 0) {
        empty.style.display = 'inline';
        notEmpty.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        empty.style.display = 'none';
        notEmpty.style.display = 'inline';
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```